# SpringBoot: @Query doesn't detect a Many-To-Many table

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I've created two *@Entities* (**Player**, **Tournament**) that are linked with a *@Many-To-Many* relationship.

#### Player.java

```java
@Entity
@Table
public class Player {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private String email;
    @Column
    private String name;

    // ...
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "PlayerTournament",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "player_id"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tournament_id"))
    private Set<Tournament> tournaments;

    // ...

}
```

#### Tournament.java

```java
@Entity
@Table
public class Tournament{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private String name;

    // ...

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tournaments")
    private Set<Player> players= new HashSet<>();

    public Set<Player> getPlayers() { return players; }

    public void setPlayers(Set<Player> players) { this.players = players; }


    // ...

}
```

Now, I want to get all *Tournaments* where a specific *Player* has played in:

#### TournamentService.java

```java
@Service
public class TournamentService {

    @Autowired
    private TournamentRepository repo;

    public List<Tournament> findTournamentsByPlayerId(Long id) {
        return repo.findTournamentsByPlayerId(id);
    }
}
```

#### TournamentRepository.java

```java
@Repository
public interface TournamentRepository extends CrudRepository<Tournament, Long> {

    @Query("select t from Tournament t join PlayerTournament pt on t.id = pt.tournament_id where pt.player_id = :id")
    List<Tournament> findTournamentsByPlayerId(@Param("id") Long id);
}
```

But this code doesn't work.

When I try to run the Application i got this **Error**:

 `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve entity reference: PlayerTournament`

The IDEE says that it `Cannot resolve symbol 'PlayerTournament'` when I hover on the table's name.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: why you are not using directly spring data for finding directly instead of using @Query ; You can use smth like List<Tournament> findTournamentsByPlayerId(Long id) the IDE will propose the good syntax for. See example here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/

Comment: It doesn't work neither like that: I got this Error: `Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'playerId' found for type 'Tournament'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are confusing JPA/JPQL and SQL.

Since you did not specify [`nativeQuery=true` in the `@Query` annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Query.html#nativeQuery()) the query is considered a JPQL query. But JPQL operates on the level of entities and does not know about (mapping) tables.

The correct JPQL query should look like this:

```sql
select t from Tournament t where t.players.id = :id
```

Of course you can stay with your current query and use `nativeQuery=true`.

And finally as [fathi correctly notes, you don't need to specify a query at all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75080018/66686) and can use query derivation with a method like.

```
List<Tournament> findTournamentsByPlayersId(Long playerId);
```

Comment: Where is *pt* coming from in the query?

Comment: @EmanuelePapa That was a typo. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `@Query` anatotion if you want to bring tournaments according to `playerId`. `Spring Boot` will handle it for you.

```
@Repository
public interface TournamentRepository extends CrudRepository<Tournament, Long> {

    List<Tournament> findTournamentsByPlayersId(Long playerId);
}
```

Comment: This is working fine! But there is a way to do it with a @Query?

Answer (score 0):

try using the below code in your tournament.java:

```java
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "PlayerTournament",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tournament_id"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "player_id"))
private Set<Player> players= new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: Still undetected